# installing older version of wine on Mavericks from tar.bz2 file

Tags: macos, wine

I remember that a program I desperately need to use stopped working after I updated wine. The last version I remember it worked perfectly on is the very version 1.5.8, which I have downloaded from here: http://www.winehq.org/announce/1.5.8 as a tar.bz2 file.

After all the struggles I have gone through trying to successfully install this specific release of wine (1.5.8) I have given up and decided to turn to this site for help.

I always installed and managed wine via MacPorts but this time it will not be possible since MacPorts doesn't allow me to install older versions of wine. I would like to ask you please if anyone could help me and tell me (explain) how to install this particular version of wine from that tar.bz2 file.

I'm using OS X 10.9, Mavericks. The program I'm trying to run is Lingea Lexicon 5 but it's not really important, I remember it worked perfectly on 1.5.8 but it doesn't on the current release 1.6.2, it crashes at start.

Please bear in mind that I'm not an experienced user of Terminal, I can do some basic things but my knowledge of commands is limited. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

### MacPorts

It is possible to install older editions of software using MacPorts. The following article explains how, [How to install an older version of a port](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort).

The example given by the article using this notation for the `tcl` package:

```
sudo port activate tcl @8.4.16_0
```

Try this for the `wine` package:

```
sudo port activate wine @1.5.8
```

### HomeBrew

Alternatively, consider installing using the [HomeBrew project](http://brew.sh). This article by David Baumgold walks through the steps required, [Installing Wine on Mac OS X](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/).

`brew` is also able to install a specific version of a package, see [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

### tar.bz2

If you want to manually install `wine` from the downloaded `tar.bz2` source, follow the steps in [Wine User Guide: 2.3. Installing Wine from source](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/installing-wine-source).

This approach will require installing the Xcode command line tools and dealing with dependencies. Because of this, I highly recommend using `brew` or another pre-built package approach.

### osxwinebuilder

An open source project called [osxwinebuilder](https://code.google.com/p/osxwinebuilder/) attempts to ease the process of building `wine` from source. This project may be helpful as it claims:

> The goal of this project is to provide easy-to-use scripts for cleanly
>   building and installing Wine and its prerequisite software into a
>   self-contained directory hierarchy on Mac OS X.

### Emulators

If you encounter problems compiling from source, consider using a PC emulator such as [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), or [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org). All these can run Windows on your Mac and thus run Lingea Lexicon 5 for you. In addition, VMware Fusion and Parallels both offer commercial support should you encounter problems.

Comment: thank you Graham for your advice but that would work only if I had installed that version previously and had updated to a newer version, which is not my case. I have not installed any version of wine but I want to install the 1.5.8 version. According to the steps on the page you provided I was not able to get it to work and I have tried everything that was described in the link. How about any way to compile from that tar.bz2 archive I have downloaded?

Comment: I have expanded the answer to mention `brew` and building from source.

Comment: Thank you for expanding your answer. The problem with installing Wine from source is that I'm a beginner with Terminal and the point of what is described in the link you provided evades me. As for the Homebrew way, I tried to check the webpage of Homebrew but I could find whether there is the 1.5.8 version of Wine available. I may try to install Homebrew and check it but I'm currently with MacPorts, which means uninstalling MacPorts and installing Homebrew.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to mention the `osxwinebuilder` project.

Comment: well, thank again, I was aware of the osxwinebuilder but that is a quite difficult process for me to perform. I am a beginner when it comes to compiling and all this unix related stuff...I would appreciate if you could provide me with a more valuable answer.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to mention emulators. This will bypass your need to compile from source.

Comment: thank you again but the emulators use the latest versions of wine

Comment: Neither Parallels or VMware Fusion have any connection to the `wine` project. Emulators simulate the underlying hardware; `wine` simulates the Windows environment. The hardware approach is different and much more reliable. I recommend engaging a local Mac expert to walk you through this problem.